# SSO MVC App compiles without errors but throws 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on

I have a very basic Single Sign On app built on VS 2015 using MVC and Web Forms. It is supposed to be a simple proof of concept and is based on some code found [here](http://arunendapally.com/post/implementation-of-single-sign-on-(sso)-in-asp.net-mvc) and [here](http://www.advaiya.com/blog/single-sign-on-sso-implementation-in-asp-net-mvc) which are essentially the same things. I've finally gotten it all converted to use .Net 4.5 but when running it on my local server it throws a 404 with no debug information.

The 404 itself wasn't initially a surprise as I was supposed to be able to change the url to one of the secure pages (for instance /WebSecApp1) which would redirect me back to the signon page but no matter what I put as the url I get the 404.

I've also tried changing the urls in the code so that they contain the port numbers for the localhost but that doesn't work either.

It was suggested to me that the RouteConfig.cs could be the culprit but I don't see how that could be since I'm calling a single page with no parameters.

I know this is kind of lite on details but does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this looks like a routing issue as you also thought it to be. Routing is essential for web api too .Pls see https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection. Does your api request look like this

```
GET http://localhost:34701/api/products/1?version=1.5&details=1
```

You do have to mention the port in the request.

Answer (score 0):

While the routing that Arathy mentioned above was partially to blame, the real problem turned out to be relatively simple. In my case simply selecting Properties->Web for each of offending pages and setting "Override application root URL" to **checked** fixed the whole problem.